# How to auto fill in OtpTextField Package Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to implement a flutter plugin OtpTextField. Is there any way to auto fill String value in handleControllers: (controller).Actually it is expecting List<TextEditingController?> value
Please help.

```
             OtpTextField(
              numberOfFields: numberOfFields,
              fillColor: Colors.white,
              filled: true,
              borderColor: kLightGrayColortwo,
              focusedBorderColor: kLightGrayColortwo,
              clearText: clearText,
              showFieldAsBox: true,
              textStyle: textStyle16Bold,
              readOnly: false,
              onCodeChanged: (String value) {
                //Handle each value
              },
              handleControllers: (controller) {
                controller = _controller.scantext;

              },
              onSubmit: (String vehicleNo) {
                _controller.vechilenostringg = vehicleNo;

              }, // end onSubmit
            ),
```

Comment: Do you mean auto fill from sms message?

Comment: no i'm getting string value in  _controller.scantext .. but the widget is expecting List<TextEditingController?> ...

Comment: As I understand from otpTextField ddocument, each number is a split textField, which mean you must have ListOf TextEditController . numberOfFields=number of TextEditController

Comment: this is the package i'm using flutter_otp_text_field. the numberOfFields is static ...which is manged just need to manage the String value which i'm getting need to populate in the handleControllers ... Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
onCodeChanged: (String value) {
    //Handle each value
},
handleControllers: (List<TextEditingController?> controllers){
    controllers[0]!.text = "1";
    controllers[1]!.text = "2";
    controllers[2]!.text = "2";
}
```